# How to Listen from bluetooth socket in android background service?

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

So I'm try to make service in Android app, this is my first App on android (& on Java too)), so i have a great number of problems. But the main problem is "architecture" my background service.

I need to set a connection via Bluetooth to device (My custom device). I have my own protocol (still in progress), and so I need in my Background service for the following things:

1. Sent something
2. Always listen to InputStream! (all the time)

How i can create this to things in my service? 
I need to create two thread's in my service?

I have tried a lot of "ideas" as to how to? and I have very huge "dirty" code... and every time I run it, it crashes.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
public BluetoothSocket socket;
public String readMessage;
public int BTC_STATE;
ExecutorService es;


public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
}


}

 public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
// ЗАПУСК СЕРВИСА
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int time = intent.getIntExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_TIME, 1);
    int task = intent.getIntExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_TASK, 0);
    String strMAC = intent.getStringExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_MAC);
    String strMESS = intent.getStringExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_MESSAGE);
    MyRun mr = new MyRun(startId, time, task,strMAC,strMESS);
    es.execute(mr);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

class MyRun implements Runnable {

    int time;
    int startId;
    int task;
    int target;
    String strMAC;
    String strMESS;

    public MyRun(int startId, int time, int task,String strMAC,String strMESS) {
        this.time = time;
        this.startId = startId;
        this.task = task;
        this.target = 1;
        this.strMAC = strMAC;
        this.strMESS = strMESS;

    }

    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
//here, depending on task id i sent reqwest. But where i need to create listning method?


}
```

In run() i have different tasks... But where i need to create listning method for my BTE socket InPutStream ?

Answer (score 0):

So no i have 3 task for service:
1)connect
2)start listening to inputStream of my BTE connection
3)to sent data

```
 try {
                        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();


                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
                        int bytes;
                        //StringBuilder readMessage = new StringBuilder();
                        String readMess2;
                        while (1!=2) {
                            try {

                                bytes = is.read(buffer);
                                String readed = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                                //readMessage.append(readed);
                                readMess2=readed;

                                intent.putExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_STATUS, DashboardActivity.STATUS_FINISH);
                                intent.putExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_RESULT, "Listning: " + readMess2);
                                sendBroadcast(intent);

                            } catch (IOException e) {

                                BTC_STATE='0';
                                intent.putExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_STATUS, DashboardActivity.STATUS_FINISH);
                                intent.putExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_RESULT, "Ошибка уха!");
                                sendBroadcast(intent);
                                serviceNotifer("ADPTTO Service", "УХО ОШИБКА " + BTC_STATE);
                                break;
                            }
                        }


                        intent.putExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_STATUS, DashboardActivity.STATUS_FINISH);
                        intent.putExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_RESULT, "STOP УХО WHILE =)");
                        sendBroadcast(intent);
                        serviceNotifer("ADPTTO Service", "УХО WHILE OUT " + BTC_STATE);


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        BTC_STATE='0';
                        intent.putExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_STATUS, DashboardActivity.STATUS_FINISH);
                        intent.putExtra(DashboardActivity.PARAM_RESULT, "GET ERROR");
                        sendBroadcast(intent);
                        serviceNotifer("ADPTTO Service", "УХО ОШИБКА 2 + " + BTC_STATE);
                    }
```

This code is working.. but just for sometime (1-2 min). Who i can listen to all the time?